# AWS S3 PreSignedUrl Upload Error

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files to S3 storage using the .Net SDK, and am seeing the following error response when PUTing to the pre signed URL provided by AWS:

The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Here's the .Net code - I've confirmed my bucket is located in USWest2.

```
var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
    // Generate a pre-signed URL.
    string folderName = "MyFolder";
    string key = "TestKey";
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
      BucketName = _bucketName,
      Key = folderName + "/" + key,
      Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
      Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
    };
    var uri = Uri(_amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request));

    // Upload a file using the pre-signed URL.
    Stream stream = ... // This is set elsewhere, contains a data stream.
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
    using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
      int bytesRead = 0;
      while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
      throw new Exception("Error uploading to AWS: " + response.StatusDescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was ultimately caused because the URL returned by the call:

```
var uri = Uri(_amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request));
```

Was of the format:

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/....
```

But AWS redirected this to:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/....
```

By using the latter URL as the beginning of my "pre signed URL", the files now upload correctly.